# How do you make spaces and dashes in COBOL

Tags: cobol

I am having a bit of trouble with my COBOL homework. I have to make a program that writes out the names of people and their social security numbers. Basically I have toy make a number like 123456789 show up like 123-45-6789 and a name like JSDOE show up like J S DOE. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do something like.

```
01 toyNumber pic 9(9).

01 yourNumber.
   03 a pic x(3).
   03 b pic x(2).
   03 c pic x(4).

01 outNumber.
   03 a1     pic x(3).
   03 filler pic x    value "-".
   03 b1     pic x(2).
   03 filler pic x    value "-".
   03 c1     pic x(4).
```

and in the procedure:

```
   move 123456789 to toyNumber.
   ....
   move toyNumber to yourNumber.
   move a to a1.
   move b to b1.
   move c to c1.

   display outNumber.
```

Or you may use "move corresponding" if you are allowed in your homework.

Hope this help!

PS: The trick for the name is the same ...

Answer (score 2):

COBOL!!

I am writing this after a long time. So, apply caution. Something like this may work:

```
01 SSN.
    03 SSN-FIRST         PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
    03 SSN-FDASH         PIC X     VALUE "-".
    03 SSN-MIDDLE        PIC X(02)   VALUE SPACES.
    03 SSN-MDASH         PIC X       VALUE "-".
    03 SSN-LAST          PIC X(04)   VALUE SPACES.

01 NAME.
    03 FNAME         PIC X(10)   VALUE SPACES.
    03 FDASH         PIC X     VALUE SPACES.
    03 FMIDDLE      PIC X(10)   VALUE SPACES.
    03 MDASH         PIC X     VALUE SPACES.
    03 FLAST      PIC X(10)   VALUE SPACES.
```

Answer (score 2):

A more modern (less ancient?) approach :-

```
STRING SSNUMBER(1:3) DELIMITED BY SIZE
       '-'           DELIMITED BY SIZE
       SSNUMBER(4:5) DELIMITED BY SIZE
       '-'           DELIMITED BY SIZE
       SSNUMBER(6:9) DELIMITED BY SIZE
 INTO PRINTFIELD.
```

Answer (score 0):

A `B` in the `PICTURE` of the receiving data-item will insert a space during a `MOVE`. For the name, a `MOVE` is all that is required. For the number, the spaces may be replaced with hyphens.

```
       data division.
       working-storage section.
       1 num-in pic 9(9) value 123456789.
       1 num-out pic 999B99B9999.
       1 name-in pic x(5) value "JSDOE".
       1 name-out pic XBXBXXX.
       procedure division.
           move num-in to num-out
           inspect num-out replacing all space by "-"
           move name-in to name-out
           display num-out
           display name-out
           stop run
           .
```

Output:

```
123-45-6789
J S DOE
```